# How to get one 2D array from multidimensional array in Python?

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray

I have a Python ndarray that is Boolean and has this shape: (32, 1600, 1600). Each layer (I visualize the 1600x1600 as a layer and the 32 as 32 layers), from 1-32, has a varying number of True and the Trues might be located at different index in its respective 2D layer. I want to "flatten" (don't know if that's the right term) this from 32 to 1, so that the resulting array is (1600, 1600) with every True carrying over to its corresponding place in the result. This is a very simplified example of my starting multidimensional array. The array is Boolean, with True/False, but I used 0 for False and 1 for True in this example:

```
array([[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 1, 0], #two "Trues"
        [0, 1, 0, 1, 0], #two "Trues"
        [0, 1, 0, 0, 0], #one "True"
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 1, 0], #two "Trues"
        [0, 1, 0, 1, 0], #two "Trues"
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]])
```

I want the final array to look like this. Every True location is carried over to its corresponding place in the new array. Since it's Boolean, it shouldn't be cumulative.

```
array([[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 1, 0], #two "Trues"
        [0, 1, 0, 1, 0], #two "Trues"
        [0, 1, 0, 1, 0], #two "Trues"
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]])
```

Comment: You would read the first 2D array from the 3D array, right?

Comment: @Hamzawi Yes, I would.

Comment: If the name of your array is x. Then, use this x[0]

Comment: @Hamzawi they seem to want to `or` all elements along the first axis.

Comment: `(sum(list(arr))>0)*1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have an array of booleans, let's create one.

```
a = np.array([[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]], dtype=bool)
```

You want to perform the `or` operation along the first axis. To do this, you can simply take the sum along the zeroth axis, and find if the elements are greater than zero.

```
a.sum(axis=0) > 0
```

gives:

```
array([[False, False, False, False, False],
       [False,  True, False,  True, False],
       [False,  True, False,  True, False],
       [False,  True, False,  True, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False]])
```

To convert it to an integer array, simply multiply this by 1:

```
1 * (a.sum(axis=0) > 0)
```

gives:

```
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]], dtype=bool)

result = 1*np.logical_or.reduce(arr, axis=0)
```

Comment: I misunderstood you because of the verb flatten which mean converting the array from higher dimensions to lower ones. For instance, you have 3D array (32, 100, 100) and you want to flatten it 2D array. In this case, the new 2D array size should be (32*100, 100) = (3200, 100).

Comment: You could use also flatten in this context but you could have explained more what type of processing between the 2D arrays should be to reduce the size which was 'logical or'

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that I was looking for "logical or". I figured my verbiage could have been confusing, but I was at a loss for words.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you're looking for, and I think it should be easy enough to convert this back to True / False as you described. If you need any help please comment.

```
arr = [[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]]

new_arr = [ [ 1 if arr[0][i][j] == 1 or arr[1][i][j] == 1 else 0 for j in range(len(arr[0][0])) ] for i in range(len(arr[0])) ]

print(new_arr)
```

Output:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
 [0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
 [0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: Looping over numpy arrays in a list comprehension is a waste of the power of numpy.

Comment: I tried your answer. My way of determining "correct" answers was to plot the array as an image. I could compare the images to an image that overlapped all 32 "layers" in one layer. Your solution only returned a little less than half of the True values. I used np.unique(arr, return_counts=True) to find out how many Trues there were in the other two answers and in your answer. They both returned 383937 true and yours returned 129557 true. I'm not sure what is missing. I  appreciate your effort.